# Extracting repeating attributes from one continuous string

Tags: java, data-structures, string, dictionary

I have a string with has two types of separator.

```
String X = "20001=EDTS~^20002=USA~^20003=1170871875~^20004=1~^20005=0~^773=~^665=~^453=2~^448=0A~!447=D~!452=1~!~^448=0A~!447=D~!452=17~!~^11=001111652533408~^";
```

`~^` denotes lone values

where `~!` denotes groups of values.

```
448=0A~!447=D~!452=1~!~^448=0A~!447=D~!452=17~!~^
```

previously I was working off the assumption there was no repeating groups of data and simply mapping to a map based on the key being equal to the tag number. However this will not for for the repeating groups as they will overwrite.

**EDIT** I want to take values from this string and map them to a Different Objects attributes. basically the number to the left refers to a tag and the value is just the value. So tag 20002=USA, I will need to map the value USA to an attribute within my new object. Invalid values are just defaulted values so that flag up that they have been assigned but not got a value

Now I'm doing a bit of head scratching to think of a better way to map the data and with the groups. maintaining both the tag and the value associated with it.

Comment: I think you might want to clarify how your strings are to be interpreted. What's the meaning of "="?

Comment: basically the number to the left refers to a tag and the value is just the value. So tag 20002=USA, I will need to map the value USA to an attribute within my new object. Invalid values are just defaulted values so that flag up that they have been assigned but not got a value.

Comment: a group of values that map to the same tag.

I get a stringmsg through with it I must take the values out of it.

Comment: @Will What tag would that be? What tag should the values in `448=0A~!447=D~!452=1~!` be mapped to?

Comment: you're thinking too closed. I want the ability to take any value from any tag and map it to an Attribute in my new Object.

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm trying to understand the message format, so that I can answer the question on how you should build your datastructure.

Comment: the tags can be just an int since they are just a whole number that seems fine but the values within would prob be best just as an object as I can convert it to whatever format the new object requires. You are quite right that this is all in the data structure

Comment: Show us input and expected output. make sure your input includes "edge cases" so we can understand what you're talking about - you're not being clear, so a unit test like example will help a lot

Comment: Input will be that string. Output (what I will be assigning the new values of my new object. This new object is not editable, I'm using a predetermined object. Simply populating it's attributes with values from this string based on the tags. The attributes within the predetermined object are:
Calendar
double
String
int
Enum (which I'm writing converter methods feed into a case statement to choose the correct enum)
Hope this helps any more questions just fire away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eek... bad data format. JSON would be a much prettier. URL encoded parameter strings would better too. Both would allow for arbitrary nesting of groups if that ever happens.

But perhaps something like this?

```
String groupDelim="~!";
String entryDelim="~^";
String pairDelim="=";

String[] groups = X.split(groupDelim);
int groupId = 0;
for(String group:groups){
   String entries = group.split(entryDelim);
   int entryId = 0;
   for(String entry:entries){
      String[] pair = entry.split(pairDelim);
      /* now do stuff with */
      groupId; // for sort order if it matters
      entryId; // for sort order if it matters
      String key = pair[0];
      String value = pair[1]; 
      entryId++;
   }
   groupId++;
}
```